# 3 div liquid design

Tags: html, css

I making 3 div (col) design with left and right divs with fixed size , centered div as liquid (in %) as:

```
.left{
width:10px;
float:left;
}

.right{
width:10px;
float:left;
}
.center{
width:100%;
float:left;
}
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="left">  LEFT   </div>
<div class="center">CENTER</div>
<div class="right"> RIGHT     </div>
```

But it is showing the divs vertically (in separate lines) as:

```
left div
centered div (occupying whole page)
right div
```

How to dispaly them in horizontal manner as:

```
left div      centered div       Right div
```

THanks...

Comment: 10px + 100% + 10px = Over 100% width of the page. Since the middle element is the 100% one, it puts the others on the top/bottom of it.

Comment: Did you try `width:auto` for the middle div?

Comment: Check out this article: [Equal Height Columns with Borders](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/08/equal-height-columns-using-borders-and-negative-margins-with-css/).  Item 3 is for 3 columns.

Comment: @Clyde Lobo: upon giving `width:auto` for center div, it depends on the contents in center div. If ,for suppose, text is too long in center,  then divs appear vertically ,in next line instead of appearing horizontally.

Comment: @aLearner : I doubt this would be possible only using css. You might have to use js.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this - you may find these pre-made solutions work best: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm

Comment: Those layouts are quite solid, and I've used that site many times. Even though there's not much to your answer, +1 because I would suggest this over any of the fragile layouts others have come up with so far.

Answer (score 0):

Its logically impossible.

If the center div is 100% width, there is no room for `.left` and `.right`

Its better you specify all the width in `%`. to make them coincide perfectly.

```
.left{
width:1%;
float:left;
}

.right{
width:1%;
float:left;
}
.center{
width:98%;
float:left;
}
```

---

**Update:** Since, the target is to get a fluid container in the `.center`. Here is the [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/vhkBm/).

Comment: I think the goal is fixed width columns with a fluid center, so it's a little trickier than this.

Comment: And along that line of thought, if you want all the `div`s to be spaced out evenly, use `width:33%` for all.

Comment: @Mike: You're missing 1% there... so not quite even. Besides, who's talking about that?

Comment: @Madmartigan It sounded that like that's what a Learner was asking about... I may have misinterpreted his question.

Comment: @Starx: Haha sorry, I don't mean to be grumpy - it's just the internet making me sound that way. I will add more smilies next time :) :) :0 :p

Answer (score 0):

By setting `width:100%;` on `div.center`, you are forcing it to the full width of its container, leaving no room for the other divs to float alongside it.

A good option is to nest `div.right` and `div.left` in the container.

```
<div class="center">
  CENTER
  <div class="left">LEFT</div>
  <div class="right">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

Given the following CSS:

```
.center {
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
}

.left {
  width:100px;
  float:left;
  background-color:green;
}

.right {
  width:100px;
  float:right;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

This will consume the whole width of the page, while allowing for fixed pixel widths of the left and right columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this:

Live demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kFPke/3)

You can remove the `text-align:center` from `.main` and play with the `padding` to have your text aligned the way you want it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="left">LEFT</div>
    CENTER
    <div class="right">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 40px 0 40px;
    background: red;
    min-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

.left, .right {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 40px;
    position: absolute;
}

.left {
    left: 0;
    background: green;
}

.right {
    right: 0;
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: @Madmartigan remove the `height` from `.main`. I updated my answer.

Comment: No dice: http://jsfiddle.net/kFPke/4/ These layouts can be tricky. Usually wrapper divs are needed to put together something solid with equal height columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
}

.center {
    padding: 0 100px; // Same value as width of left and right
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this one

`<div style='border:1px solid red;float:left;'>Left</div>`

`<div style='border:1px solid blue;float:right'>Right</div>`
   
`<div style='border:1px solid green;'>Center<div>`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fosterz/fbXVA/)

Answer (score 0):

This was done by [Glish](http://glish.com/css) back in '99.

```
#left{
    position: absolute;
    width:10px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

#right{
    width:10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; 
    right: 0px;
}

#center{
    margin-left: 11px;
    margin-right: 11px;
}

... 

<div id="left">  LEFT   </div>
<div id="center">CENTER</div>
<div id="right"> RIGHT     </div>
```

I did it in a JSFiddle, but because you have text in there that will natively be larger than 10px wide, I didn't bother including it. It works though. It should also work inside any block element.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this one - http://jsfiddle.net/Jn7Bq/4/

```
 <div class="left"> LEFT </div>
 <div class="center"> CENTER </div>
 <div class="right"> RIGHT </div> ​
```

**CSS**

```
.left{
width:100px;
background:red;
float:left;
}
.right{
width:100px;
background:red;
float:right;
}
.center{
position:absolute;
left:100px;
right:100px;
background:green;  
}​
```

Experimental